# Spawn Child Processes To Write To a Log File

Tags: c

I am looking at writing a program where a parent process will spawn multiple child processes. Each child will write to a .log file that was created by the parent. However, each child should write to a spceific section of the file.

What would be the best way to do this? I understand I will need to use `fork()` and I know how to create the file. What would I need to do have a child write to specific section of a log file?

Is there a function that allows writing to a file at a specific location?

This is book exercise.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html

Comment: Please define how "What would I need to do have a child write to specific section of a log file?" is supposed to work in the format of the log file. That is, what the results you are looking for look like. Once done, ping me.